# Unable to populate boolean field from index value

Tags: indexing, lucene

My Lucene **web** Index is correctly populated with the field `parsed_is_line_manager`.

In the `BasePerson` class, I thus added this field:

```
[SitecoreIgnore]
[IndexField("parsed_is_line_manager")]
public virtual string IsLineManager { get; set; }
```

(I tried with bool instead of string without success)

This field, on a site associated to the **web** index, is always `null`.

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: this is my model

```
[Serializable]
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{7D18B94B-CC01-4FC5-AC26-76BB2A7392FB}", AutoMap = true)]
public class BasePerson : ImageTemplate, ITagged<Tag>, IPerson, ISectors<Sector>, IEquatable<BasePerson>, IDivisionMultiSelection
{
    // LOTS OF FIELDS

    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexableIntToBoolConverter))]
    [IndexField("parsed_is_line_manager")]
    public virtual string IsLineManager { get; set; }

    // MORE FIELDS
}
```

And this is my `IndexableIntToBoolConverter` class:

```
public class IndexableIntToBoolConverter : TypeConverter {
    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the <param ref="sourceType" /> can be converted from
    /// Hint: This is the type declared in your codebase
    /// </summary>
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return sourceType == typeof(bool) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the <param ref="destinationType" /> can be converted to
    /// Hint: This is the value you want to store within the index
    /// </summary>
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        return destinationType == typeof(int) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the object from the index to your type
    /// </summary>
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        return value != null && ((int)value >= 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the object from your type to the index
    /// </summary>
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        return ((bool)value) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the field marked as Stored?

Comment: Yes it is. I can inspect the index with Luke, and it's there.

Comment: Create a new TypeConverter for Int/String to Bool Conversion - I followed this - https://kylekingsbury.com/mapping-integers-values-to-boolean-values-within-solr-with-the-contentsearch-api/

Comment: The article is about Solr, my index is with Lucene. Would that still work, @AbhayDhar?

Comment: Why not , IMO typeconverter is searchprovider agnostic

Comment: Nope @AbhayDhar - it doesn't work, and breakpoints inside the `IndexableIntToBoolConverter` class are never hit.

Comment: did you try after removing [SitecoreIgnore]?

Comment: At the same time, ContentSearch can see the index and operate correctly based on its value.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat Removing `[SitecoreIgnore]` has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Please share your Model class , have u decorated the bool property with the new IndexableIntToBoolConverter

Comment: @AbhayDhar added both my model and `TypeConverter`.

Comment: public virtual string IsLineManager { get; set; } this property should be boolean ??

Comment: I tried both boolean and string.